# select as field in Linq

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am new to linq and trying to convert following sql query to linq;

```
  select c.ClientID , c.ClientName 
  , ISNULL((select 1 from clientcontactaccess cca 
        where cca.clientid = c.clientid and ClientContactID = 2141  ), 0) 'ClientAccess'
  from Clients c
  where c.GroupID = 1
```

I have tried this so far but don't know where to include where clause;

```
 Dim query = (From c In db.Client Select New With _
               {Key .ClientID = c.ClientID, _
                 Key .ClientName = c.ClientName, _
                 Key .ClientAccess = (From cca In db.ClientContactAccess Where cca.ClientID = c.ClientID And cca.ClientContactID = _contactID)})
```

Updated:

I have managed to come this far but clientAccess field returns no value. I need to return either 1 or 0.

```
  Dim query = (From c In db.Client Where c.GroupID = 1 Select New With _
               {Key .ClientID = c.ClientID, _
                 Key .ClientName = c.ClientName, _
                 Key .ClientAccess = (From cca In db.ClientContactAccess Where cca.ClientID = c.ClientID And cca.ClientContactID = _contactID)})
```

Comment: You tried that so far... but.... what?

Comment: Before the Select - `From c in db.Client Where c.GroupID = 1 Select New...`

Comment: Linqer is a SQL to LINQ converter tool. It helps you to learn LINQ and convert your existing SQL statements.

Comment: `From c In db.Client Where ... Select`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to convert your SQL query but I'm not sure this is work for you and I think converting your query result something like this in C# and you need little bit change for your need.

```
var result=from c in Clients select 
new {c.ClientID,c.ClientName, cca.Where(x=>x.ClientId=c.ClientID 
&& x.ClientContactId=2141).Any()} where c.GroupID==1;
```

Comment: 1. OP is using VB.NET, not C#.  2.  I'm pretty sure that what you wrote won't compile, as I don't believe a where can come after a select in LINQ.